# How to suppress prompt when running Linux script from Windows?

Tags: windows, vbscript, plink

I wrote the following VBScript in order to run the Linux script from windows by using the `plink.exe` tool.

user - **root1** , 
password - **adhdh**

**my VB script:**

```
Const Host = "110.18.3.32"
Set Sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Const cstrSftp1="""C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\plink.exe"""
strCommand11 = cstrSftp1  & " -ssh -pw " & " adhdh " & "root1@" & Host & " /var/tmp/script "  
Sh.Run "cmd /k " & strCommand11, 1, True
Set Sh = Nothing
```

But there is little problem

When I run this script on the first time I get the following prompt from `plink`:

> Store key in cache? (y/n)

So in order to solved this issue by adding `echo y` I change the line in the script as follows:

```
strCommand11 = echo y | cstrSftp1  & " -ssh -pw " & " adhdh " & "root1@" & Host & " /var/tmp/script "
```

but after I run the new script it fails with this error:

> expected end of statement

I also tried

```
"echo y | cstrSftp1  "
```

But still I get other error.

Please advice what I need to change in my script?

Comment: `strCommand11 = "echo y | " & cstrSftp1  & " -ssh -pw " & " adhdh " & "root1@" & pHost & " /var/tmp/script " `

Comment: this is correct behaviour. You can create a public/private ssh-key-pair with putty and copy the public key to the linux-machine to prevent it. There is a putty tutorial for this... google it!

Comment: @roland thx its work please add your answer so I can to vote for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strCommand11 = "echo y | " & cstrSftp1 & " -ssh -pw " & " adhdh " & "root1@" & pHost & " /var/tmp/script "
```

Comment: Roland I have another question - Is it possible from the VB script to versify if the script run successfully on the Linux machine

Comment: if yes please add your solution to your answer

Comment: The `Run` method returns the exit code of the run program: `rc = Sh.Run("cmd /k " & strCommand11, 1, True)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `echo y | plink.exe ...` is a rather clumsy way to solve this issue. It's better to import the remote server's public host key (e.g. `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`) into the registry to prevent the prompt from appearing in the first place. There's a [Python script](http://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty/contrib/kh2reg.py?view=markup) for converting the public key from the format used on Linux hosts to the format PuTTY uses in the Windows registry. You can write the converted value to the registry like this:

```
Const Host = "110.18.3.32"

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys\rsa2@22:" & Host _
  , "0x10001,0x9b95f6ac6cf5...", "REG_SZ"

'rest of your code here
```

Comment: one question is it possible to delete the remote server public keys from the windows machine , so I will test it another time - if yes please show me how to delete it ?

Comment: Sure. You can simply delete the value from the registry, either manually via regedit, or with a script, e.g. `reg delete "HKCU\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys" /v "rsa2@22:110.18.3.32" /f` in batch/CMD or `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegDelete "HKCU\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys\rsa2@22:110.18.3.32"` in VBScript.